# Node js module mkdirp only creates half the directories

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to use [mkdirp](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp) for a project, but when I feed it a var with my dir path I want created, it only creates the first half of it. I've installed the module locally with npm. I'm using Node v0.10.20 on a Raspberry Pi.

This is how it looks:

```
var filePath = "upload/home/pi/app/temp";
mkdirp(filePath, function(error) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        ...
    }
});
```

I don't get an error creating the path, but it only creates "upload/home/pi", however if I run my script again, it creates the rest of the directory structure. Upload is a
directory in the current working directory which is the user home.

I emailed the author of the module who suggested that it could be because I'm using a flash drive as my medium, which in turn lies about when IO operations are complete, which I guess confuses node.js to think it has successfully written the path to disk. How should I tackle my problem? I guess I can do a check on if the directory was created, and loop that until it has, but that feels like the wrong thing to do. Any suggestions welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Yep, looping is the wrong thing. Have you tried doing it manually, i.e. mkdir with a callback that calls mkdir with a callback […] that calls mkdir?

Comment: No, I haven't yet, I'll have a look at that, thanks for the suggestion. Too bad to invent the wheel though! And I'd still like to know why it acts like this.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp/issues/25) code?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I ended up doing as @minitech suggested.

Comment: could you share the code please?

Comment: Please mark this as solved or delete.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this synchronously:

```
var filePath = "upload/home/pi/app/temp";
mkdirp(filePath)
```